# Files that have first line containing a particular string

Tags: encoding

I have noticed that a lot of files on my Linux OS have first lines that contain `^?ELF^A^A^A@^` or some variation, at the very least many contain `^?ELF`.

What does ELF stand for and what is this type of encoding called?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: great thanks for your patience so is any file that contains such a header to be considered an "ELF file"?

Comment: ah ok elfdump nm got it

Comment: If you want to know what a file type for a file is, ask your system to tell you.  eg. to see what type of file 'blah' is, you can use `file blah`.   `file /bin/ls` reports "*/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=c6ffa89317550907a309fb98de530a440e3e625a, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped*" on my system  (which can contain acronyms yes, but version info too and more precise than guessing)